# ManyToMany Relationships Within Configuration Entities

Tags: entities

I come from a symfony/doctrine background where ManyToMany relationships are usually called out in the entity using annotations.  I'm having trouble understanding how this is done in Drupal 8 and haven't found any good documentation.  Lets take this example.

```
namespace //...
use //...

class MenuExtensionsEntity extends Menu implements MenuExtensionsInterface {

    /** @var MenuExtensionEntity @ORM\..purposely blank */
    protected $parent;

    /** @var MenuExtensionEntity @ORM\..purposely blank */
    protected $children;

    /** @var int; */
    protected $weight;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
     }
    //... all needed getters and setters below.
 }
```

We'll assume this satisfies the interface.  How is this represented in drupal 8 where children has a ManyToOne and parent has a OneToMany relationship.

Comment: Drupal doesn't use Symfony entities, nor the ORM, so the concept doesn't really transfer

Comment: I just don't understand how a DBA is supposed to work with this.

Comment: "Work with" in what respect? Config entities don't contain relational data...their data is stored in a serialised PHP string in the `config` table, and as yaml files in exported config files in the file system. There's nothing special for a DBA to get involved with really

Comment: These are good things to know.  I really had no idea that it was stored like that at all.  Why even call an entity, it's really more like Value Object. VO.  I'm quite new to drupal but I've been doing symfony/doctrine since 2010.  I feel like d8 is going the longest way around the mountain too get to what will just be a OO drupal version of symfony and doctrine.